# How to partition the local hard disk in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, partitioning, sony-vaio

I'm using Windows 8 and I want to partition my hard disk.

My local disk is of 440 GB and in disk management I partitioned the hard disk into local disk E and F from only one local disk C. But my local hard disk C is 221 GB and it is not further partitioned.

Also, it s saying that the available free space for partitioning is only of 110 MB.

So, I want to know how I partition the hard disk and have hard disk C with around 100 GB.

Comment: Can you post screenshots of your Disk Utility as it is right now? It's confusing the way you're using drive letters in your description.

Comment: What @MarcusChan means is, post screenshots of your current partition layout as shown by [Disk Management](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/windows-8/a/disk-management-windows-8.htm).

Comment: Sorry again, that's what I meant! @Karan I feel like you're always fixing my mistakes :D

Comment: @MarcusChan: I'm sure you'll do the same for me sometime. :D

Answer (score 1):

I won't be 100% sure until you post a screen shot of your disk management- but it sounds like you are running into an issue that I came across in the past where you can no longer partition the HDD even though you have plenty of available space.

If you are having the same issue I was then your disk management will show your C drive on the right side of the drive.  What I learned in this situation is that you cannot extend a drive to the left- only to the right.  To fix this I ended up booting into my ubuntu flash drive and using GParted to move my entire C drive to the left side of the disk (this was done with GParted because you cannot move the C drive on the disk while windows is booted).  But **beware** this will break your MBR and you **will** have to use your windows disc to boot into command prompt and repair the MBR.  Here are the commands that will fix your MBR (worked for me in Windows 7 and 8):

/FixBoot. Writes a boot sector onto the system partition to start Windows

/ScanOs. Scans all disks for Windows installations and displays them to you.

/RebuildBcd. Scans all disks for Windows installations and prompts you to pick the ones you want to add to the BCD.

Answer (score 1):

there are several software available for the partition. We can use EASEUS partition master.
for download link [click here](http://www.filehippo.com/download_easeus_partition_master_home/)

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged. Could you please go into a bit more detail?

Comment: easus partition manager is a software which helps in partition the hard disk  in a more easier and simpler way. It's tutorials can be available in the internet. download the software and use it. it's really easy

Answer (score 0):

If you want to further partition an exisiting partition, the OS automatically calculates the amount of space that can be utilized to create the partition.

From your message, I assume that you do not have much free space left on your C drive, hence only option is to take a data backup and re-install windows and during installation create the required partition size.